# How can I make two legends of two different plots with the numeric scale?

Tags: legend, plot, copernicus

I want to campare two images about Surface water temperature from Copernicus, I've imported them and cropped them, but the legends with the colours are slightly different, how can I do for creating a unique comparable legend?

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(lswt21, main = "Lake Surface Water Temperature in 2021")
plot(lswt22, main = "Lake Surface Water Temperature in 2022")
```